# Generate TextFile from THIS XML

Tags: xml, text-files

We have learned the basics of XSLT this year and I thought I could use it to extract data from a website

The website features general knowledge https://www.indiabix.com/general-knowledge/questions-and-answers/ and since it's all well formated I thought it'd be posible to import this data in my flashcard application anki

Is this something that could be doable by learning the language a little bit?
Also, is there a better form out there to post this kind of question. I feel like I am at the wrong place

Comment: Yes, you probably are in the wrong place, but since I'm big Anki fan - are you trying to take one of the categories on the page [(for example, Indian Culture)](https://www.indiabix.com/general-knowledge/indian-culture/) and turn in into a multiple-choice Anki deck?

Comment: sounds great, thanks